# Overflow X not working with CSS Transform property

Tags: css

I am making the website that will have rotated divs. 
I am using twitter bootstrap. Code for one of the divs is:

HTML:

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 cold-sm-12 col-xs-12 rotadedDiv-one">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotadedDiv-one {
   background: #412B57;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-1deg);
   transform: rotate(-1deg);
   padding: 130px 10% 80px 10%;
   z-index: 5;
}
```

Problem that I have is that since divs are rotated, there is a small overflow (about 10-20px). I tried to get rid of it with:

```
html, body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And with adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to rotadedDiv-one, but they don't work. They remove the scroll bar from bottom, but you can still scroll to right if you click mouse wheel and move to right, or by selecting text and going to the right.

Also, I tried to make wrapper div with `overflow-x: hidden;` that will be in , but it didn't work. Any help would mean a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you seeing the overflow?  Do you mean the DIV is partially outside of the page?

Comment: Yes. You can scroll to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use normal [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) instead of [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)?  `overflow` has better support, and will keep scroll bars from appearing in both the x and y directions.

```
html, body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

`overflow-x` and [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) are handy, but are still listed as "experimental", and may not play very well with proprietary properties like `-webkit-transform`.

They breakdown like this:

- `overflow` changes how an element behaves if any of its children are at least partially rendered **anywhere** outside of it.
- `overflow-x` changes how an element behaves if any of its children are at least partially rendered outside to **the left or right** of it.
- `overflow-y` changes how an element behaves if any of its children are at least partially rendered outside **above or below** it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Overflow: hidden;
```

Hope works.

Comment: A little explanation will help make your answer understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It's late 2021 (six years later!) and I can confirm the issue is still present at least in Chrome using basic coding and no hacks. I'm developing a CSS-rotated scrollable list and no Overflow solution of a parent has helped me thus far - percentage nor pixels defined. I have a feeling this has something to do with the rendering engine, meaning the rotate is applied "after" container dimensions are pronounced.

Only way I could produce a overflow: hidden on rotate was using position: absolute for the rotated container. This means you probably will need to define height somewhere so it isn't exactly organic solution.